# Why this program can not find saddle point in (4*4)(or higher) array?

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void)
  {
     int n, m, i, j, k, q, r, maxr = 0, state = 0, count= 0;
     puts("Enter two numbers represents two dimensional array, N * M");
     puts("This program will find the saddle points");
     scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
     int ar[n][m];
     for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts("Enter the number in array");
        scanf("%d", &ar[i][j]);     //store the number form user
        printf("Array accepted %d, and this number's location is [%d][%d]\n", ar[i][j], i, j);
    }
}
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) //print the two dimensional array
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           printf("%3d", ar[i][j]);
        }
    putchar('\n');
   }


    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)   //find the saddle point
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {   
            if(ar[i][j] > maxr)     //compare the number is i row until find the biggest
            {
                maxr = ar[i][j];
                q = i;
                r = j;
            }
            else
               continue;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        if (ar[q][k] < maxr)    
        {
            state = 0;
            break;
        }   

        if (ar[q][k] > maxr)
        {
            r = k;
            state = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (ar[q][k] == maxr)
        {
            state = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    count++;
    if (state == 1)
        printf("The saddle point is (%d), location is [%d][%d]\n", ar[q][k], q, k);
    else
        printf("The %d row does not contain a saddle point\n", count);
}
}
```

This program is designed for finding saddle points. Saddle points in two dimensional array, means the biggest point in row, but the smallest point in column. for example, the first row 1, 2 the second row, 3, 4, then the saddle point is 2.

The problem I met is, this program can find 3*3 array's saddle point, but failed to find 4*4 (or higher) array's saddle point.

for example,

```
2, 3, 9, 5
6, 7, 8, 3
0, 5, 7, 5
2, 1, 8, 3
```

Then the saddle point is row 3 column 3, 7. but the program can not find.

so what is the problem, is the logic problem? but i can find the 2*2 or 3*3 array's saddle point..

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger and stepped through the code line-by-line?

Comment: `gdb` is your friend. Learn it, live it, breathe it.

Comment: @abelenky I am a novice in programming…so I have not use debugger…

Comment: how is 2,2/7 the saddle point? 7 is neither largest/smallest in the row, and it's the biggest point in the column. That goes entirely against your stated rule.

Comment: @MarcB well, (2,2) is 7, but in row 2, 7 is not the biggest.

Comment: "biggest point in row, smallest point in column". 2,2/7 meets neither of those.

Comment: @MarcB i wrote wrong row and column numbers…I changed…is row 3 column 3…

Comment: **No, no, no, no.**  It is ***more*** important that a novice learn to use a debugger.  *(An expert programmer can inspect the code, and determine what will happen.  A novice programmer **must** see the code in action).*  Please learn to use a debugger ***immediately***.

Comment: @abelenky oh, thanks, i will try it.

Comment: I agree with @abelenky, if you step through this with a debugger you will easily find your problem.  You don't say which compiler you are using, but virtually every compiler since the early 90s has a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done as follows:  (a) Step through rows sequentially (b) Have function identify column in which largest row member occurs (c) Have function inspect that column to see whether indicated member is smallest.  These don't have to be "functions" per se, but should be neatly and methodically organized as functional units.

I implicitly assume that you don't have any duplicate values in any rows or columns in this exercise--unless those duplicates are guaranteed not to be the extrema in their rows/columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should have reset value of max within loop.

This will find saddle a saddle point in each column.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
     int n, m, i, j, k,max;
     puts("Enter two numbers represents two dimensional array, N * M");
     puts("This program will find the saddle points");
     scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
     int ar[n][m];
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++)            
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
            puts("Enter the number in array");
            scanf("%d", &ar[j][i]);     //store the number form user
            printf("Array accepted %d, and this number's location is [%d][%d]\n", ar[i][j], i, j);
        }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){ //print the two dimensional array
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
           printf("%3d", ar[j][i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ //for each row
        max=0;
        for (j = 1; j < m; j++) //find biggest in the row
            if(ar[i][j] > ar[i][max])     
                max=j;

        for (k=0; k < n; k++)   // if there are bigger element than this in that column, break
            if (ar[k][max] < ar[i][max])    
                break;
        if(k==n)    // if there were no bigger elements in the column
            printf("The saddle point is (%d), location is [%d][%d]\n", ar[i][max], i+1, max+1);        
    }
}
```